# Is persistence via scheduled tasks possible if the user is not elevated?

Tags: malware, windows

As far as I can tell, scheduled tasks may only be created by those in the Administrators group by default. Does that mean that persistence can't be achieved via this method without gaining elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `schtasks.exe` without elevation, though you can't create tasks for other users without knowing their passwords, or for system accounts without knowing an admin password. For example, the line `schtasks /create /sc once /st 14:08 /tn testcalc /tr calc.exe`, run from a non-elevated prompt, successfully popped calc.exe for me at the expected time. It's possible it wouldn't have worked if I wasn't a member of the Administrators group at all, but I doubt that; unless there's a bug in the way schtasks considers permissions, it shouldn't have "seen" the Administrators group membership on my security TOKEN, since for a non-elevated process that group is only present in the DENY list (I can't do something if admins are prohibited), not in the ALLOW list (I can't do something even if admins are permitted).

Comment: It worked on my fully updated Windows Server 2019 install with a regular, non-admin user.